# Dynamic link with knockout js templates

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to create a link that calls `ActionResult Index(Guid? keyID)`, whenever I click on City.

This is what I have for now but it's not working. I'm new to KnockoutJS MVVM and somehow I'm stuck on this. Any help is highly appreciated.

```html
<script type="text/html" id="display">
    <td style="width: 7%"><a href="/Employee/Sections/Index" data-bind="text:keyID" value="text: strCity"></a></td>
    <td style="width: 7%" data-bind="text: fName"></td>
    <td style="width: 10%" data-bind="text: lName"></td>
    <td style="width: 6%" data-bind="text: blnActive"></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-success kout-edit">Edit</button></td>
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should probably edit your question and be more specific. Tell us what "not working" means, include the relevant logic (we need to [repro](http://sscce.org) your situation), and tell us what you've tried so far and why that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standard MVC routing to pass KeyID to your controller action, you are probably looking for something like this:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: '/Employee/Sections/Index/' + keyID() }, text: strCity"></a>
```